# Using phpQuery for data abstraction

Tags: php, phpquery

i have to fetch some data from a web page. i want to use phpQuery for that.when i try for the example

```
require_once('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
phpQuery::browserGet('http://www.google.com/', 'success1');
function success1($browser) {
  $browser
    ->WebBrowser('success2')
    ->find('input[name=q]')
      ->val('search phrase')
      ->parents('form')
        ->submit();
}
function success2($browser) {
  print $browser;
}
```

i got a error message like

```
Fatal error: Class 'phpQuery' not found in /var/www/TantraProjects/Testing/pregmatch.php on line 4
```

i cant know that is phpQuery class not exist or something else.

Comment: Where is phpQuery.php saved? It must be in `include_path`

Answer (score 0):

This clearly is a problem where the php engine is not able to find your phpQuery file. So the problem is in

```
 require_once ('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
```

line. Is `phpQuery`folder in the `Testing` Folder or `TantraProjects` folder? If latter, change:

```
 require_once '../phpQuery/phpQuery.php';
```